# Mutliple Node.js processes on one VPS

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to set up two node.js processes on 1 VPS with reverse NGINX proxy, with the following config I receive "CANNOT GET" error.

I've tried many different configs however I haven't gotten any to work with both processes...

```
upstream crypto {
   server 127.0.0.1:3010;
}


upstream other {
   server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}


server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nft-memes.io.key;
    server_name nft-memes.io;

    location /crypto  {
        proxy_pass          http://crypto;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection          "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   tcp;
        proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy       true;
    }

    location /other {
        proxy_pass          http://other;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection          "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   tcp;
        proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy       true;
    }
  }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting 502 Bad Gateway error or a 404 from node? "cannot get" sounds like the later, which then is not related to your nginx but instead your not taking into account the URL path in your routing in the app

Comment: thanks for the reply! I am getting 404 cannot get, but if I change the port in nginx, it points to the other node process.

Comment: its still pointing to the wrong node.js, even though there are on different ports, namely 3000 and 3010

Comment: do you have `/crypto` in your routing? i.e in express `app.get('/crypto', ...)` or are you thinking `/crypto` is turned into `/`?

Comment: I have both in the second node.js, a route for / ( just in case ) and a route for /crypto

Comment: I'm such a tool, the app route was set to post inside node.js, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!!!